# Implementing a simple factorial function using continuation passing style

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to implement a function that returns a factorial in OCaml but I don't know if I'm actually using a continuation passing style:

```
let fact n =
  let rec factorial n cont = match n with
    | 0 -> cont ()
    | _ -> factorial (n-1) (fun () -> cont () * n) in
  factorial n (fun () -> 1)
```

It seems to me that I'm not really delaying a computation so much as just displacing the computation in my code.

Answer (score 6):

Well, actually your code is very interesting. It is not very usual, but it is tail-recursive, so it will work. I will show you a "usual" way of doing CPS. Usually, your are returning from a function using a continuation, that why it is a good idea to name you continuation something like `return`. Also, usually you start with an identity function as an initial value for a continuation. And finally, you're using the continuation as an assembly, where you build the answer.

```
let factorial n = 
  let rec loop n return = match n with
    | 0 -> return 1
    | n -> return (loop (n-1) (fun x -> x * n)) in
  loop n (fun x -> x)
```

So in this example, I pass a continuation that will accumulate and, finally, build the answer.

To summarize, three simple rules:

1. return with continuation
2. start with identity
3. update a continuation on each step.

But anyway, you function is an interesting solution.  aIndeed, what you're using is building a lazy list of closures. In each step of your computation, you're creating a closure, that uses a previous closure and multiplies it by n. When you reach 0, you call this chain of closures. So, this is a O(n) in space, but instead of stack, you're using heap. Of course, my solution is O(n) in space. I'm just clarifying.

Comment: Ah, this seems more right but I was under the impression that continuations shouldn't be making calls to the "upper-level" function (loop in this case).

Comment: I think @newphew92 is right here. The typical CPS-style factorial is somehting [like this](https://gist.github.com/gallais/bf1d202cb13c9248b3c3): you start by evaluating `(n-1)!` and then multiply this  value `v` by `n` before returning using the provided continuation.